# Invalid right aligned chapter and section titles

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, right-to-left, bidi

I'm trying to write a bidirectional (English/Hebrew) document in xelatex and polyglossia. For some reason, when I enable Hebrew as a secondary language, all the chapter and section titles become right-aligned, even when they are in English. Do you know why this happens?

Here's a simple example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello world}
\end{document}
```

And this is how it looks:
[image: The example results]

Comment: It is because you are using an ancient version of `bidi` package. Please update your TeX distribution. The current version of `bidi` package is 11.158.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea Ubuntu lagged so much behind. Installing the latest tex-live now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vafa Khalighi suggested, Upgrading tex-live to the 2011 version solved the problem.

Comment: In few weeks, TeXLive 2012 will be out. So if you can, install TeXLive 2012 and update your TeX distribution once in a while.